# Reference to $C^{1/\epsilon}$-topology in a paper

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, differential-topology

I am reading a paper in which a curve is referred to as being '$\epsilon$-close to a horizontal line in the $C^{1/\epsilon}$-topology'. There is no explanation of what this means, and as an undergraduate student I have not come across this topology (or even know if it's standard notation). The concept of a [Whitney topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies) has similar notation but seems only defined for integers and I'm not sure whether this notation is just a coincidence. Has anyone come across this and could please explain it? A google search has returned nothing. Thanks!

Edit: didn't include the paper as the above is mentioned as a comment rather than part of the main text. But [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.5110.pdf) it is for those interested, remark 4.2 on page 9.

Comment: If possible, it might not hurt to cite the paper here. Perhaps someone with more experience in the field can tell what it should mean from context, but not from the statement by itself.

Comment: @MeesdeVries added :)

Comment: Generally speaking, $C^\alpha$ for positive real $\alpha$ is shorthand for $C^{n,\gamma}$ where $n=\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$ and $\gamma=\alpha-\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$. This in turn represents functions which have $n$ continuous derivatives, the $n$th of which is $\gamma$-Holder continuous. When the domain is compact, the usual norm on this space is the sum of each $\| f^{(k)} \|_\infty$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$, plus $\sup_x \limsup_{y \to x} \frac{|f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}$.

Comment: Note that what I just said is wrong if $\alpha$ is an integer: for example, $C^1$ consists of continuously differentiable functions while $C^{0,1}$ consists of Lipschitz functions.